# Display an correct format date on apex

Tags: oracle-apex

I have a query that performs ok to display the dates to generate a graph well ordered, but I want to display the month first, but I can't get the issue.

My query is:

```
select null link, to_char(DATA,'YYYY-MM') label, COUNT(ID) value
from  "my_table"  
group by to_char(DATA,'YYYY-MM') ORDER BY label
```

And result is:

- 2013-09 2
- 2014-09 1
- 2015-06 1
- 2015-09 8
- 2016-02 2
- 2016-05 7
- 2016-06 9

When I tried to change the label's display mode there was an error:

```
select null link, **to_char(DATA,'MM-YYYY') label**, COUNT(ID) value
from  "my_table"  
group by to_char(DATA,'YYYY-MM') ORDER BY label
```

> ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression...

Comment: The expression in the `select` has to match the expression in the `group by`.  If you are fomatting the string one way for the `select` list, you'd need to format it the same way in the `group by` clause.  You and I can work out that changing the order of the expressions in the format mask doesn't change how data is grouped but database engines aren't yet that smart.

Comment: Hi, Justin, All right! Thanks